# Getting "access forbidden" error with SendGrid marketingdb php

Tags: php, sendgrid-api-v3

So, I'm able to send emails with Sendgrid just fine.  My API key is set to "full access."

But whenever I try to interact with my contactdb (adding a contact, getting a list...anything), I get an "access forbidden" error.

```
require_once 'config.php'; 

require '../sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php';

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

try {
    $response = $sendgrid->client->contactdb()->lists()->get();
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Any idea why this is happening or more importantly, what the fix is?

Answer (score 1):

I just spent an hour figuring this out. They haven't updated the docs. That's all. They have a new Marketing API that does not reflect the documentation.
See more [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/896)

Meanwhile, you can try again with `marketing()` instead of `contactdb()`

```
$response = $sendgrid->client->marketing()->lists()->get();
```